# Clicking on 'a' element in navbar get stuck in touch-mode, but works perfectly otherwise

Tags: javascript, html, css

First post on stackoverflow!

I've got an project were there's one issue left before it's done.
I've coded a dynamically-made nav-bar with JS 
And I've done so that when clicking on 'a' element it scrolls smoothly to the section that 'a' is linked to. (check the function scrollTo() ).
Addition to that I've got another function that checks if a section is in portview and if it is then it should active an active-class to that section and ALSO highlight the 'a' item in the nav-bar.
The purpose for this is ofcourse to improve UX.

The code works perfectly, except for **one** issue when I try it on phone/ipad devices in Google Chroe devops.
When clicking on an 'a' item, and after it scrolls to the right function, the clicked 'a' get's highlighted as it should, and when scrolling around the sight, the right section in the viewport is getting highlighted in the nav-bar, as it should, but the clicked 'a' item is stil highlighted.
Like it's sticky.

I can't wrap my brain around it and I'm thinking it may be because of it being a touch because it works perfectly on non-touch.

Here's the code:

```
function scrollTo() {
for (let anchor of anchors) {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        sectionId = anchor.getAttribute('href');
        elementToScroll = document.getElementById(sectionId);
        elementToScroll.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start'
        });
    });
} }

function makeActive() {
for (let section of sections) { 
    let attr = section.getAttribute('id');
    let a = document.querySelector(`[href="${attr}"]`);
    let box = section.getBoundingClientRect(); 
    if (box.top <= 150 && box.bottom >= 150) { 
        section.classList.add('your-active-class');
        a.classList.add('menu__link__active');
    }
    else {
        section.classList.remove('your-active-class');
        a.classList.remove('menu__link__active');
    }
} }


document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
makeActive(); });
```

EDIT: The problem with the "sticky" was because of touch and hoover state, so this is now solved! :)

Comment: try touchstart  or touch witht click like addEventListener('click touchstart',

Comment: @AhmedSunny Didn't work. When I changed the addEventListener type from 'click' to 'click touchstart' the links don't worky anymore on click.

Comment: don't _change_ it, _add_ it. You need an eventlistener for _both_ `click` and `touchstart`, so turn that event handler into its own function, then call that function in response to both events.